# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mysql.so'

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, mysql, php

I am running PHP 5.6 on Linux.  When I try to load a PHP page, I'm getting the following PHP error.

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mysql.so'

When I look in the directory /`usr/lib64/php/modules/` indeed there is no shared object php_mysql.so.   So, it looks like php extension for mysql isn't installed. So I run the yum install:

`yum install php56w-mysql`

and I get the message that:

> Package php56w-mysql-5.6.10-1.w6.x86_64 already installed and latest
> version

So, is my php.ini configuration incorrect?   Should I point it in a different place to look for php-mysql extension?

Linix version information: Linux version 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-64012) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) )

Ran suggested command to view where modules are installed:

```
rpm -ql php56w-mysql

/etc/php-zts.d/mysql.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/mysqli.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/pdo_mysql.ini
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mysql.so
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mysqli.so
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pdo_mysql.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so
```

Looks like I installed a php-zts and there is a similar issue here: [Enable PHP-ZTS and MPM Workers in Apache to lower memory footprint, but still keep MySQL?](https://serverfault.com/questions/359078/enable-php-zts-and-mpm-workers-in-apache-to-lower-memory-footprint-but-still-ke)

Comment: Which version of linux?

Comment: @Shadur updated my answer with Linux information

Comment: Looks like Fedora, but I'm not that sure...might as well be RHEL

Comment: Try `rpm -ql php56w-mysql`, that *should* (it's been a while since I used RPM) give you a list of where the package's files are stored. There may be a mismatch between where it stored them and where php thinks they're supposed to be.

Comment: @Shadur it looks like the shared objects are in php-zts folder. I tried updating the extension_dir location and got a different error. `Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,NTS`

Answer (score 1):

Find the following line in your `php.ini`:

```
;extension=php_mysql.so
```

Remove the semicolon, which is serving as a comment, then restart apache.

If that doesn't work, report back...

This has been transcribed from [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097377/php-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib64-php-modules)

Comment: I checked the `/etc/php.ini` config and it has a line extension=php_mysql.so uncommented

Comment: Assuming something else is missing, please attempt [How to Install a LAMP stack on CentOS, Fedora, or Red Hat](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-install-a-lamp-stack-on-centos-fedora-or-red-hat) using the "Individual Commands" Section.  If that works, I'll add the commands here.

Comment: What about `extension=mysql.so` in `php.ini`? Just checked a closely related RPM package (CentOS 7) and in that case, the module was actually found under `/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so`! If that works, the packager should get a decent slap, because of breaking common file naming due to doing things his own way!